# Orders of data in Divided Differences and Lagrangian Interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

As we know that the order of data points i.e. x values do not matter in Divided Differences and The Lagrangian Interpolation.  Why is that? What happens if we arrange them in order? better interpolating polynomial value can be obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^Ny_k\prod_{\begin{smallmatrix}k=1\\ k\neq j\end{smallmatrix}}^N\frac{x-x_k}{x_j-x_k}$$

is unchanged by a permutation of the $(x_i,y_i)$, since addition and multiplication are commutative.